# Are there any good firewalls available?

Tags: security, firewall

Does the android platform have any firewall application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that Android includes iptables, which is the standard firewall for any Linux.
What I have no information about is whether iptables is compiled into the kernel used on all phones, but you might get more information out of [this thread in the xda-developers forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=444004).

Answer (score 5):

DroidWall is pretty good, but it requires root, of course.

http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.googlecode.droidwall

It allows you to control on an app-by-app basis which applications can access the network, and has separate permissions for Wifi and 3g.

Answer (score 1):

As per @TREE's answer above - DroidWall is no longer developed nor supported and is forked into a superior version called [AFWall](https://github.com/ukanth/afwall) found on Github.

For those who do not wish to tinker with the code,  here's the direct linky to the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall)

AFWall works very well with the newer Ice Cream Sandwich and upwards.

And yes it has the same requirement as the old DroidWall, i.e. requiring root.