# Are there any "iptables like" firewall for Android?

Tags: security, firewall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any good firewalls available?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/143/are-there-any-good-firewalls-available)

How can i make my Android more secure with a firewall? Are there any legal/offical ways to do it?
Thank you!

Comment: That quest has an answer which discusses iptables.

Answer (score 1):

[DroidWall](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.googlecode.droidwall.free) is an Android front end for iptables. Root is required though.