# Is it possible to restrict a single app on the S6 from connecting to the internet?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6

Is there a way to stop a particular app from establishing ANY sort of outgoing connections to the internet but I still want the app to be able to use the internet when I want to but still be able to block "unverified  connections at the same time. Such a thing exists?

Comment: What are "*unverified connections*"? You can use a [firewall](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=firewall).

Comment: @Firelord Wait, those exist and work like on desktops? Any that use up minimal battery resources on the S6 cause it dies quickly already even on Power Saving mode.

Comment: Most of the apps which needs root access uses IPTABLES which itself is managed by kernel, so you can be rest assured for battery.

Comment: @Firelord Oh, do all firewalls require root access?

Comment: See:  [Closing internet access for some apps](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/106967/96277), [Are there any good firewalls available?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/143/96277), [How to limit data usage of individual apps?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29334/96277)

Comment: @Firelord Too old that thread but Play store no-root firewalls that seem to be updated more frequently than root ones.